# Vagrant and interactive ansible

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I am running `ansible` provisioner within `vagrant`.

At some point, I need some user input as follows:

```
     - pause:
        prompt: "Port 6443 seems in use and / or kubernetes cluster already initialized! Proceed with resetting cluster? (Y/n)"
      register: reset_cluster
      when: some_condition
```

However, the output is as follows:

> [WARNING]: Not waiting for response to prompt as stdin is not interactive

and provisioning just continues.

Any way to go about this?

Comment: Hi there, this looks like a bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you please provide further context as to what you're doing, what tools/programs you're using, and what you're ultimately trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ansible prompts [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html). Maybe you could do:
And then in your code:

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "reset_cluster"
    prompt: "If so and so is already initialized would you like to reset?"
    default: "Y"
    private: no
```